# Python logging: Can I pass arguments to a custom handler in json config file

Tags: python, logging, python-3.6

Ive read the docs, but did not find any mention of this.
Is it possible to pass parameters to a custom logging.handler class inside a json configuration file?

```
"handlers": {
    "custom_handler": {
        "class": "logging.CustomHandler",
        "args": ['a', 'b'] # <------------------------            
        "level": "INFO",
        "formatter": "custom"
    }
},
```

Where the handler class definition is :

```
class CustomHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, argA, argB):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = argA
        self.b = argB
    def emit(self, record):
        <Some code>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every key in the handler section that is not one of `class`, `level`, `formatter` or `filters` is passed to handler constructor as keyword argument. Example:

```
"handlers": {
    "custom_handler": {
        "class": "logging.CustomHandler",
        "level": "INFO",
        "formatter": "custom",
        "argA": "spam",
        "argB": "eggs"
    }
}
```

<sub>This also means that having a handler with a constructor arg named `class`, `level`, `formatter` or `filters` is a bad idea...</sub>

Source: [Configuration dictionary schema](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#configuration-dictionary-schema).

Comment: Thank you. That's something I did not know (obviously)

Comment: Glad I could help!